# PHP Fatal Error: Class "Controller" not found

Tags: php, linux

estoy intentando ejecutar un script de PHP en la línea de comandos de Linux con:

```
php -f ClienteController.php
```

y me sale este error en la línea de comandos:

```
PHP Fatal Error: Class 'Controller' not found in (__directorio__)
```

El código de ClienteController:

```
<?php
    class ClienteController extends Controller
{
    (contenido)
}
```

Lo raro es que tengo este proyecto en el localhost y si me funciona, pero también lo tengo duplicado en un servidor Linux y aquí es donde me da el error y no sé porqué. He intentado hacer un include y un require de la clase Controller y sigue sin funcionar. 
No sé si puede ser por alguna configuración que habría que hacer con los ficheros de configuración que vinen en Linux, ya que también me lanza este error junto al otro:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - 'usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so': cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

-RUTAS:
   -ClienteController: `\var\www\html\ClubVinos\clubdevinos\protected\modules\cliente\controllers\`
   -Controller:

```
\var\www\html\ClubVinos\clubdevinos\protected\components
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes q hacer una inclusion del fichero q contiene la clase Controler de la q extiendes

```
   <?php 
require_once "Controller.php"
class ClienteController extends Controller {
```

O también puedes hacer la definición de dicha clase en el mismo fichero

```
    <?php 
class Controller{}
class ClienteController extends Controller {
```

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar. He editado la pregunta. Muchas gracias por responder!!

Comment: @Csc99 nos falta más información para poderte ayudar, la primera de las opciones q té comento sirve para incluír el fichero donde tienes dicha clase recuerda q tienes q poner la ruta completa al fichero, o relativa al directorio donde se ejecuta la web

Comment: Ya probé a incluirlo con la ruta completa y no funciona. Si necesitas más información, no dudes en pedirla!

Comment: @Csc99 es claramente un tema de rutas de acceso, entiendo que as respetado las mayúsculas y minusculas, recuerda q Linux es case sensitive, por lo q comentas en Windows funciona y en Linux no, es un error típico e incluso las barras de las rutas de los ficheros también son problematicas

Comment: Exacto, con Windows me funciona y en Linux no. He comprobado las rutas y están bien

Comment: No estaría de más q añadieses la jerarquía de ficheros donde cuelgan los dos ficheros, y la prueba con el require y el error producido con esta opcion

Comment: Ya he puesto las rutas. El error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: : Class 'Controller' not found in (__directorio__) en es te error _directorio_ q té sale

Comment: Este:  \var\www\html\ClubVinos\clubdevinos\protected\modules\cliente\controllers\ClienteController.php

Comment: generalmente cuando no funciona en GNU/linux y si en Windows , es porque GNU/Linux es CaseSensitive verifica si tu clase se llama exactamtente igual

Comment: Añade al ejemplo el require talcual love estes poniendo, lo digo por q según eso estas buscando la clase Controller en el directorio modules\cliente\controllers\ClienteController.php y no me parece coerente

Comment: Sí, he comprobado que las rutas estén bien escritas. También he probado poner los requires de dos maneras: require('../../../components/Controller.php'); require('/var/www/html/ClubVinos/clubdevinos/protected/components/Controller.php');

Comment: Lo siguiente q nos queda es veamos la clase Controller

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente te falta indicar dónde se encuentra la clase Controller de la que extiendes.

Tendrías que agregar arriba, algo como:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

O similar dependiendo de la estructura de tu proyecto.

Comment: Esto solo funcionaria si tuviese un método autoload() definido q conozca como cargar dicha clase